# Error en conversion de un DataViewGrid a Excel: System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, excel, windows-forms, datagridview, exportar

Buen dia chicos, estuve tratando de exportar de DataGridView a Excel por uno de los videos que ví en YouTube, pero desafortunadamente no funciono una parte del código... Adjunto las funciones a continuación:

```
//Aqui hay una funcion que hace referencia al boton de "Generar Excel" en la aplicacion de forms...
//dgvReporte es el DataGirdView que se genera en la aplicacion y deseo exportar esos datos a Excel
private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvReporte.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        exportarExcel(dgvReporte);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No hay datos existentes para exportar");
    }
}

//Esta funcion es exclusiva para Generar el excel:
private void exportarExcel(DataGridView tabla)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);

        int IndiceColumna = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in tabla.Columns)
        {
            IndiceColumna++;
            excel.Cells[1, IndiceColumna] = col.Name;
        }

        int IndiceFila = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tabla.Rows)
        {
            IndiceFila++;
            IndiceColumna = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in tabla.Columns)
            {
                IndiceColumna++;

                excel.Cells[IndiceFila + 1, IndiceColumna] = row.Cells[col.Name].Value;
            }
        }
        excel.Visible = true;
    }
```

En la funcion de "exportarExcel(DataGridView tabla)" en la penultima linea de código:

```
excel.Cells[IndiceFila + 1, IndiceColumna] = row.Cells[col.Name].Value;
```

Me salta el siguiente error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'La signatura de tipo de este método no es compatible con interoperabilidad.'
```

Dejo capturas del comportamiento de la aplicación como referencia...

Tabla de DataGridView generada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error que genera el compilador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Paquetes NuGet Instalados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sinceramente seguí los pasos del video al pie de la letra, pero al parecer aquí no me funciona... Espero y me puedan ayudar y/o a poder exportar ese DataGridView (dgvReporte) a Excel, gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Te dije en tu post anterior que el código va en formato texto. Las imágenes solo sirven para demostrar algo, corrige eso

Comment: Gracias @FranqoBalsamo, ya hice corrección previa de la pregunta que realicé... En cuanto a la anterior realizare en breve las correcciones correspondientes. Es mi primera vez usando Stack Overflow.

Comment: Parece que hay un problema con el tipo de datos que exportas a Excel y que no lo puede tratar. Para solucionarlo, prueba a forzar que  lo que se exporta a Excel es texto:
excel.Cells[IndiceFila + 1, IndiceColumna] = row.Cells[col.Name].Value.ToString();
Mira a ver, ya que no tengo posibilidad de probar. Si falla, habria que ir colocando un Select Case para adaptarse a cada formato de columna...(fecha, numero...)

Comment: Estuve investigando el problema externamente y tambien no le hayo solucion... Probablemente sea por tema de versiones del sistema operativo que uso y/o excel. Los videos que he visto los usuarios por ejemplo usan windows 7 con versiones del visual studio del 2013 o anteriores, mientras que yo actualmente utilizo windows 11 + excel en su ultima version. Igual muchas gracias por la ayuda @pcandido. Encontre otra forma de convertir de un DGV a excel facilmente :).

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que estas intentando agregar datos a una variable de tipo Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application, deberias usar una variable de tipo Worksheet y a ella gregar los datos,prueba con esto:

```
public void exportarExcel(DataGridView tabla)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
        Workbook libro;
        Worksheet hoja;

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        if (excel == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Excel no se encuentra instalado apropiadamente.");
            return;
        }

        libro = excel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        hoja = (Worksheet)libro.Worksheets.get_Item(1);


        int IndiceColumna = 1;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in tabla.Columns)
        {
            hoja.Cells[1, IndiceColumna] = col.Name;

            IndiceColumna++;
        }

        int IndiceFila = 2;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tabla.Rows)
        {
            IndiceColumna = 1;

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in tabla.Columns)
            {
                hoja.Cells[IndiceFila, IndiceColumna] = row.Cells[col.Name].Value;

                IndiceColumna++;
            }

            IndiceFila++;
        }

        excel.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionarlo asi , espero le sirva a alguien

```
public void exportaraexcel(DataGridView tabla)
{
    
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new 
          Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);

        int IndiceColumna = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in tabla.Columns)
        {

            IndiceColumna++;

            excel.Cells[1, IndiceColumna] = col.Name;

        }

        int IndeceFila = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tabla.Rows)
        {

            IndeceFila++;

            IndiceColumna = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in tabla.Columns)
            {

                IndiceColumna++;
            object cellValue = row.Cells[col.Name].Value;
            excel.Cells[IndeceFila + 1, IndiceColumna] = cellValue != null ? cellValue.ToString() : string.Empty;



        }

}

    excel.Visible = true;
```